# When $M^{**} \cong M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Can we characterize when the canonical map $M \rightarrow [[M, R]_{R \text{-mod}} , R ]_{R \text{-mod}}$ sending $a$ to $\hat{a} : [M, R]_{R \text{-mod}} \rightarrow R$ sending $\phi$ to $\phi(a)$ is an isomorphism?

If $R$ is a field and $M$ is finite dimensional over $R$, then this map is an isomorphism. Are there other criteria on $R$ and $M$ for this map to be an isomorphism? What is a general context for this to hold?

Comment: I doubt there is a nice characterization.  For instance, here is a remarkable theorem: for $R=\mathbb{Z}$, every free module $M$ satisfies $M^{**}\cong M$ iff no measurable cardinals exist.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh dear, I'd love to have some references.

Comment: Such modules are called *reflexive* modules. There is a paper by Pierre Samuel (in french), entitled *Modules réflexifs et anneaux factoriels* (Reflexive modules and U.F.D.s).

Comment: A simple observation - far from a general classification - is that this holds for projective and finitely generated $M$ (informally, this may be somewhat analogous to "finite dimensional" over any ring). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620239/finitely-generated-projective-modules-are-isomorphic-to-their-double-dual) is a proof.

Comment: @juandiegorojas: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132073/homomorphisms-from-powers-of-z-to-z